Better way to return rows WITHOUT a left join match?
We have two tables - Table1 and Table2 - in a SQL Server database, and we are trying to identify rows in Table1 that do not have a match in Table2.  Right now, this is accomplished using nested views:
View1:
CREATE VIEW vw_View1 
AS
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.col4
GO

View2:
CREATE VIEW vw_View2
AS
SELECT col1
FROM vw_View1
WHERE (col2 is null)
GO

I know of one other way to achieve this without nested views, but so far this has resulted in slow execution times:
SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.col3 NOT IN
(
    SELECT t2.col4
    FROM Table2 t2
)

Is there a better way to accomplish this without using nested views or "NOT IN"?

Try not exists instead of IN perhaps?

Out of interest, what is the reason for not wanting to do a left join?

Are you sure your tables are indexed properly? I would expect Table1 (col3) INCLUDE (col1, col2) and Table2 (col4)

I think, with index on Table1(col3) ans Table2(col4) this is better way.
Try this
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.col4
WHERE (col2 is null)

Or view
CREATE VIEW vw_View1 
AS
SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.col4
WHERE (col2 is null)

You can write
SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)  is null

Or
SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE not exists (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)

There will be implicit JOIN.
I think, @siggemannen suggestion is best case.
create table Table1 (col1 int,col3 int);
insert into Table1 values
   (1,10)
  ,(2,11)
;
create table Table2 (col2 int,col4 int);
insert into Table2 values
   (10,10)
  ,(20,12)
;

4 rows affected

SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON 

SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)  is null




StmtText
StmtId
NodeId
Parent
PhysicalOp
LogicalOp
Argument
DefinedValues
EstimateRows
EstimateIO
EstimateCPU
AvgRowSize
TotalSubtreeCost
OutputList
Warnings
Type
Parallel
EstimateExecutions




SELECT t1.col1FROM Table1 t1WHERE (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)  is null
1
1
0
null
null
1
null
1
null
null
null
0.0066635
null
null
SELECT
False
null


|--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1006] IS NULL))
1
2
1
Filter
Filter
WHERE:([Expr1006] IS NULL)
null
1
0
9.6E-07
11
0.0066635
[t1].[col1]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([t1].[col3]))
1
3
2
Nested Loops
Left Outer Join
OUTER REFERENCES:([t1].[col3])
null
2
0
8.36E-06
15
0.00666254
[t1].[col1], [Expr1006]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1]))
1
4
3
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1])
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
2
0.003125
0.0001592
15
0.0032842
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1005]>(1) THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
1
5
3
Assert
Assert
WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1005]>(1) THEN (0) ELSE NULL END)
null
1
0
4.8E-07
11
0.00336998
[Expr1006]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2


|--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=Count(*), [Expr1006]=ANY([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col2] as [t2].[col2])))
1
6
5
Stream Aggregate
Aggregate
null
[Expr1005]=Count(*), [Expr1006]=ANY([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col2] as [t2].[col2])
1
0
1.1E-06
19
0.00336902
[Expr1005], [Expr1006]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2]), WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4]))
1
7
6
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2]), WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4])
[t2].[col2]
1
0.0032035
8.07E-05
15
0.0033649
[t2].[col2]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2



SELECT t1.col1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE not exists (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)




StmtText
StmtId
NodeId
Parent
PhysicalOp
LogicalOp
Argument
DefinedValues
EstimateRows
EstimateIO
EstimateCPU
AvgRowSize
TotalSubtreeCost
OutputList
Warnings
Type
Parallel
EstimateExecutions




SELECT t1.col1FROM Table1 t1WHERE not exists (select col2 from Table2 t2 where t1.col3=t2.col4)
1
1
0
null
null
1
null
1
null
null
null
0.00665978
null
null
SELECT
False
null


|--Nested Loops(Left Anti Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([t1].[col3]))
1
2
1
Nested Loops
Left Anti Semi Join
OUTER REFERENCES:([t1].[col3])
null
1
0
8.36E-06
11
0.00665978
[t1].[col1]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1]))
1
3
2
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1])
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
2
0.003125
0.0001592
15
0.0032842
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
1
5
2
Top
Top
TOP EXPRESSION:((1))
null
1
0
1E-07
9
0.00336702
null
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2]), WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4]))
1
6
5
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2]), WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4])
null
1
0.0032035
8.07E-05
11
0.0033649
null
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2



SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.col4
WHERE (col2 is null)




StmtText
StmtId
NodeId
Parent
PhysicalOp
LogicalOp
Argument
DefinedValues
EstimateRows
EstimateIO
EstimateCPU
AvgRowSize
TotalSubtreeCost
OutputList
Warnings
Type
Parallel
EstimateExecutions




SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2FROM Table1 t1LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.col4WHERE (col2 is null)
1
1
0
null
null
1
null
1
null
null
null
0.00666798
null
null
SELECT
False
null


|--Filter(WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col2] as [t2].[col2] IS NULL))
1
2
1
Filter
Filter
WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col2] as [t2].[col2] IS NULL)
null
1
0
9.6E-07
15
0.00666798
[t1].[col1], [t2].[col2]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join, WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4]))
1
3
2
Nested Loops
Left Outer Join
WHERE:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1].[col3] as [t1].[col3]=[fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2].[col4] as [t2].[col4])
null
2
0
1.672E-05
15
0.00666702
[t1].[col1], [t2].[col2]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1]))
1
4
3
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table1] AS [t1])
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
2
0.003125
0.0001592
15
0.0032842
[t1].[col1], [t1].[col3]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
1


|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2]))
1
5
3
Table Scan
Table Scan
OBJECT:([fiddle_50ed91c7837e4018b52de926d6c64ec8].[dbo].[Table2] AS [t2])
[t2].[col2], [t2].[col4]
2
0.0032035
8.07E-05
15
0.0033649
[t2].[col2], [t2].[col4]
null
PLAN_ROW
False
2



fiddle
